# Which memory setup is faster?

Tags: memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the number of sticks of RAM influence speed, for the same total amount of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/247174/how-does-the-number-of-sticks-of-ram-influence-speed-for-the-same-total-amount-o)

Let's say I want to have a computer with 4GB memory. I could use one 4GB memory chip, or two 2GB memory chips. Would using two 2GB memory chips be slightly faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all else being equal 2x2Gb will be faster if the two are paired properly and your chipset supports dual-channel memory.

Comment: Why is it faster? How much faster is it?